# DB9 Serial communication

Tags: serial, communication, at-commands

I am getting some strange character displays on hyper terminal, after establishing communication with my GSM modem using the appropriate baud rate. When I type "AT", it appears to get repeated  or display strange characters (as though the baud rate were not correct) on the hyper terminal screen as "AATT". And all other AT commands get repeated as well, but what surprises me is that they all respond to the command. "AATT"(having typed "AT") give me "OK".

What could possibly be the problem? I am connecting the Modem to the DB9 using a MAX232. Below is the response

---

```
øatt    
OK  
aaütø     
OK  
aatt++ücnnmmiiþ?ø                 
+CNMI: 1,0,0,0,0                

OK  
aattþ+ccssccss??ø                 
+CSCS: "UCS2"             

OK

RING

RING

RING

NO CARRIER

øat++ücnnmmii==11<,22<,00,,00,,00ø

OK

aattþ+ccssccss==""GGêSMM""ø

OK

Øaüt++ccmmögæf==11ø

OK

aatt

OK

aaüt++ccþnmii??

+CNMI: 1,2,0,0,0

OK
```

---

Comment: A suggestion. I thing [ZOC Terminal](http://www.emtec.com/download.html#zocfiles) is the best to works with modems.

Comment: @Ricardo - [at-commands] is a pretty young tag and there was a bunch of former question related to it. Sorry for giving you a lot of review job.

Comment: @Ricardo -Thanks, I will keep your advice in mind. On the other hand we should not talk about it here, but [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24959/editing-behaviour).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have local echo turned on in your terminal emulator. Turn it off.

Alternatively, turn off echo on your modem:

```
ATE0
```

Comment: I would opt for the former!

Comment: @Dave I'd turn it off on the modem if I were writing an AT command parser in software. That way it can send "AT\n" and expect "OK", not expect "AT\nOK"

Comment: Ah, excellent point, I wasn't thinking it through all of the way and putting myself in the position of the modem.  Thanks!

Comment: Yea...i turned of the echo using ATE0, and the repetition stops. But how can we explain for the strange characters been displayed. Also, I am using a baud rate of 9600, but when I changed the baud rate to 115200, i did not experience this strange situation. Unfortunately, my intended application (in communicating with a micro controller) is designed to work for 9600. Finally, how can i turn off the echo of my terminal emulator?

Comment: Please note: you should **only** use `\r` to terminate an AT command line (e.g. `"AT\r"`), neither `\n` not `\r\n`. See *5.2.1 Command line general format* in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to rectify the problem and totally avoided the repetitions.
Simply use a 1k pull-up both at the TXD and RXD pins of the UART, to VCC. So all work with any baud rate. The problem was simply an issue with voltage levels.

Thanks to all who contributed!